# Scalatest mocking a db

Tags: scala, testing, mocking, scalatest

I am pretty new to using Scala/Scalatest and I am trying to write a few test cases that mock a db.

I have a function called FindInDB(entry : String) that checks if "entry" is in the db, like so:

```
entry match {
  case `entry` =>
  if(db.table contains entry) {
    true
  }
    false
}
```

FindInDB is called in another function, which is defined in a class called Service.
I want to be able to mock the db.table part. From reading scalatest I know I could mock the class that FindInDB is defined and control what the function that calls FindInDB returns, but I want to test the FindInDB function itself and control what is in db.table through mock

Comment: you know... a boolean expression already returns true or false depending on if it's true or false, putting an `if` statement around it isn't really necessary

Comment: Yes, there are other things happening in the method but to simplify the question I took them out

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB mockup framework such as jOOQ, or my framework Acolyte. Acolyte can mock DB at JDBC level, for any project based one JDBC directly or indirectly (e.g. JPA, EJB, Anorm, Slick): you describe for each test case which JDBC result (resultset, update count, error) is for which statement.

It allows to mockup exactly the same JDBC data would be exchanges by your app/lib with expected DB, with many advantages for testing: unit isolation, simplicity (no need to setup/tear down test DB with fixtures).

Documentation is online at http://acolyte.eu.org/ .

There is a Scala DSL which is easily usable for testing (examples with specs are available in documentation).